# How to click and launch javascript class from wordpress menu-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

Hi I am trying to create a custom link inside a WordPress menu item using jQuery. This link, which works as a stand alone button using 'items_wrap', is what I am trying to create in the WordPress menu:

```html
<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><li><a id="buttonLang" class="changeLang" href="#">' . $otherLanguage . '</a></li>%3$s</ul>
```

Basically I want the above link to work when I click the Wordpress menu link.  Am I am trying to do this using jQuery but not sure if I am on the right track:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var menuID = jQuery(‘#menu-item-1022’);
  findA = menuID.find(‘a’);

findA.click(function(event){
    $("#buttonLang")[0].click() // Not sure what to put here.
    
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you have a menu item and a stand alone link and you want to click on the link when someone clicks on the menu item?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding.  Basically I want this: 

<a id="buttonLang" class="changeLang" href="#">' . $otherLanguage . '</a>

to run in when I click the dropdown list item in the menu.  The language of the site changes to the other language when it is clicked.  This works when it is not inside the Wordpress navigation menu so I just need it to work when it is an item on the menu.  Its probably very simple but I am new at this.  thx

Comment: If the buttonLang link is already there when the page loads `$("#buttonLang")[0].click()` should work fine. If you're inserting the link dynamically, then use `$("#buttonLang")[0].trigger('click')` and catch the click event using `$(document).on('click', '#buttonLang', function);`